# Is it possible to combine blog post sharing counts on Facebook for two URLs?

Tags: facebook, blogs, facebook-sharer

I just migrated some blog posts to a new URL, and I lost all my Facebook sharing counts.

Is there a way to tell Facebook about the new URL for these posts so that I can have a combined sharing count for both URLs, since they are the same post?